# flutter_pagewise library does not preserve page (scroll) state on tabbing away

Tags: flutter, dart, pagination, flutter-pagewise

I am using the `flutter_pagewise` library and have implemented a paginated grid as per the library's documentation (following their example at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pagewise/example), which grabs placeholder images and text via the network.

In my app, I have 2 pages (one is called `PaginatedGrid` and the other is called `SearchPage`) that I can tab to via a BottomNavigationBar. However, when I tab to the `SearchPage`, then tab back to `PaginatedGrid`, the paginated grid scroll state isn't preserved. The pagination starts from the very beginning and the screen is scrolled back to the top.

```
import 'package:myproject/my_events/my_events_page.dart';
import 'package:myproject/search/search_page.dart';
import 'package:myproject/widget/paginated_grid.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageWrapperState createState() => _PageWrapperState();
}

class _PageWrapperState extends State<PageWrapper> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  int _curIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _pages;
  final bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  final Key searchPageKey = PageStorageKey('searchKey');
  final Key paginatedGridKey = PageStorageKey('paginatedGrid');

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pages = [
      PaginatedGrid(key: paginatedGridKey),
      SearchPage(key: searchPageKey)
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageStorage(
        bucket: bucket,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          key: PageStorageKey(_pages[_curIndex].runtimeType.toString()),
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: <Widget>[SliverAppBar(), _pages[_curIndex]],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int i) {
          setState(() {
            _curIndex = i;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: _curIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Browse',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Search',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Any help would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an indexedStack is a solution that worked! The paginated state is preserved on navigation to another tab from the bottom navigation bar.

Instead of using a PageStorage widget, use an IndexedStack widget.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: currentTab,
        children: pages,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
```

The solution is described here: https://medium.com/@codinghive.dev/keep-state-of-widgets-with-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-bb732214bd11